# Reasons for the lag of smooth scrolling on lazy column in android jetpack compose

Tags: android, scroll, android-jetpack-compose, lag, lazycolumn

I just use the lazy column for showing the my custom items on the view. I tried with this with itemsIndexed with as well. But lagging issue is not solved.

What can be the reasons for this?

Comment: You can use ```key``` for uniquely identify the item and also test you rapp in release mode you will notice the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you did not share any code anyone cannot give a specific reason for this to you but generally there are bunch of optimization tricks you can apply like:

- passing a unique key  to your LazyColumn,
- running it in release build instead of debug
- if your "custom items" include an image, making sure the image library use use contains a cacheing mechanism
- using `@Stable`, `@Immutable`annotations in your ui state data classes
  etc.

Comment: Thanks for your support, 2nd option was worked for my case.